# URL not responding on OS X, fine on other machine

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, url, hosts

For some reason I can't access anything on `python.org`. `nslookup` resolves the IP address, but no browser or `curl` command will fetch anything. It works fine on a VMWare Ubuntu virtual machine and on a Windows machine on the same network. I've checked there's nothing funny in `/etc/hosts`

I don't know where else to go looking for issues, can anyone suggest anything?

Running OS X 10.5 Leopard

Comment: Do all other sites work okay, e.g. www.google.com ?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers on OS X? Firefox, Chrome?

Comment: @Doug "no browser or curl command will fetch anything" - so yes

Comment: @JBRWilkinson yes, everything apart from python.org (and it's subdomains)

Comment: whoops, missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have IPv6 enabled for your network connection?

This may be related to python.org having an IPv6 address configured:

```
$ host python.org
python.org has address 82.94.164.162
python.org has IPv6 address 2001:888:2000:d::a2
python.org mail is handled by 50 mail.python.org.
```

Googling for "ipv6 python.org" brings up some interesting results such as [this Chromium bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12711). The comments indicate that a bug in OS X has been identified and that the bug still exists in Snow Leopard.

Try disabling IPv6 and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look if Parental Controls are on for that users' account - it works by proxying via a local daemon which has an heuristics-based filter would could be mistaking 'python' for a censored term.

Comment: I enabled Parental Controls for another account on my mac and had no trouble accessing python.org in Safari.

Comment: What would be behaviour be if this were the case? Currently it just times out trying to connect (after a long period of time for some apps)